# Retrieving data from a web page in Node-red

Tags: node-red

I want to retrieve data from a web page when work with Node-red.But i debug and output is empty.

[image]

Comment: Post an export of the source code of your flow so other people can import it and try it.

Comment: [{"id":"ca9e17f5.022f88","type":"http request","z":"4e8f0923.8e24f8","name":"Market Indexes","method":"GET","ret":"txt","paytoqs":false,"url":"https://www.google.com/finance","tls":"","proxy":"","authType":"basic","x":240,"y":160,"wires":[["7d0254fa.cf267c"]]}]

Comment: Edit the question, do NOT try and post code as comments. Also we have no idea what is in your template node so have absolutely no way to guess what it's doing.

Comment: Also please read the Doc about what a Good Stack Overflow question needs: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Đỗ Tùng Lâm, I see on your browser tabs that you are doing a lot of research. I wonder if you have already read this page in Node-RED flows: https://cookbook.nodered.org/http/simple-get-request. By reading git and learning how to use CSS selector, you will succeed. The picture you share shows you are on the right path. I am confident that you will be using Node-RED in no time and having a great time doing it. If you edit your original post (OP) and share your flow we will be able to give some additional advice.

Comment: thank you.I will try to learn more and more and will share my project for you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are experimenting with the flow "[Example 6.1 Retrieving data from a web page](http://noderedguide.com/node-red-lecture-6-intermediate-flows-2/)" from http://noderedguide.com

The problem is that the web page has been remodeled and is no longer using the HTML markup code used in the past. You will not be able to make that example works and this is not your fault or mistake

Be aware that this is a common issue. It is likely that at some point in the future the maintainers of a web page will change the page layout and our Node-RED flow will stop working. Therefore we have to scrape web pages with caution. Another caveat is that many web pages use javascript to dynamically generate their content. In such cases, it is tricky or complicated to retrieve the content with the HTML node.

Additional links that may help you:

https://cookbook.nodered.org/http/simple-get-request

[https://discourse.nodered.org/t/newbie-and-scraping-info-from-webpages/7282](https://discourse.nodered.org/t/newbie-and-scrapping-info-from-webpages/7282)

https://discourse.nodered.org/t/extract-elements-from-the-retrieved-html-document/8719